# convert pandas json column to multiple rows

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-cleaning, data-conversion

```
data1 = {0: [{'confident': False, 'iab': 'IAB25-3'}],
 1: [{'confident': False, 'iab': 'IAB6-6'},
  {'confident': True, 'iab': 'IAB6'}],
 2: [{'confident': True, 'iab': 'IAB16-1'},
  {'confident': True, 'iab': 'IAB16'},
  {'confident': False, 'iab': 'IAB9'},
  {'confident': False, 'iab': 'IAB9-28'}]}
```

Above format was originally the list/json in every row having = [{'confident': False, 'iab': 'IAB25-3'},{'confident': True, 'iab': 'IAB16'}] which is converted into dictionary with the help of to_dict() resulted in the data mentioned in the starting.
Main problem is that array of collection(confident and iab) can be n times and n is unknown. So, I'm not able to format it.

I'm trying really hard to convert it into below given dataframe format but haven't succeeded yet.

```
rowid   confident    iab
0       False        IAB25-3
1       False        IAB6-6
1       True         IAB6
2       True         IAB16-1
2       True         IAB16
2       False        IAB9
2       False        IAB9-28
```

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way using `json_normalize`:

```
dfs = []
for k, v in data1.items():
    df = pd.json_normalize(v)
    df['rowid'] = k
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop='index')
print(df)


   confident      iab  rowid
0      False  IAB25-3      0
1      False   IAB6-6      1
2       True     IAB6      1
3       True  IAB16-1      2
4       True    IAB16      2
5      False     IAB9      2
6      False  IAB9-28      2
```

Comment: But still in my opinion `concat` solutions here are slow, faster is change structure of data and pass to `DataFrame` constructor.

Comment: Yes concat maybe slower here I agree, but not sure why it didn't match expected output?

Comment: Oh let me change that :)

Answer (score 2):

Idea is use list comprehension for flatten values with prepend value of keys to new `rowid` key for list of dictionaries, so possible pass to `DataFrame` constructor if performance is important:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(**{'rowid':k}, **y) for k, v in data1.items() for y in v])

print (df)
   rowid  confident      iab
0      0      False  IAB25-3
1      1      False   IAB6-6
2      1       True     IAB6
3      2       True  IAB16-1
4      2       True    IAB16
5      2      False     IAB9
6      2      False  IAB9-28
```

Another solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and dict comprehension should be better is few big DataFrames in dictionary, but generally `concat` with generate many small `DataFrame`s is slow:

```
df = (pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in data1.items()})
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('rowid')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   rowid  confident      iab
0      0      False  IAB25-3
1      1      False   IAB6-6
2      1       True     IAB6
3      2       True  IAB16-1
4      2       True    IAB16
5      2      False     IAB9
6      2      False  IAB9-28
```

Comment: this approach is works with me for some Json rows, but I face this error with other json `(AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys')` any help?